# How to get Airflow db credentials from Google Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am in current need of Airflow db connection credentials for my Airflow instance in Cloud Composer.
All I see on Airflow connection UI is `airflow_db mysql airflow-sqlproxy-service`.

I would like to connect to it via DataGrip.
Another thing is if I want to change the `[core] sql_alchemy_conn` override environmental variable, how do I do it as it is restrictedw hen I add it on my env variable on Cloud Composer environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Composer isn't designed to give external access to the database. However you can connect to the GKE cluster and then access it from within the cluster. [This doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#installing_sqlalchemy_to_access_the_airflow_database) shows how to do that with SQLAlchemy, but you can also get direct MySQL CLI access by running `mysql -h $AIRFLOW_SQLPROXY_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST -u root airflow-db` instead of sqlalchemy in step 6.

Comment: I want to clean my xcoms via a dag tasks when my workflow is finished via a code like this, and it is somehow prevented

```
clean_xcoms = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='clean_xcoms',
    postgres_conn_id='airflow_db',
    sql="delete from xcom where dag_id='{{ dag.dag_id }}'",
    dag=dag
)
```

Error:
```
 could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "airflow-sqlproxy-service" (ip address) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: @Plengo Cloud Composer uses MySQL as Airflow DB, but you are using the `PostgresOperator`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to David's answer:

After following [directions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#installing_sqlalchemy_to_access_the_airflow_database) to connect to the GKE cluster worker the `$AIRFLOW_SQLPROXY_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST` env variable did not exist for me . Instead, I parsed the connection details from the SQLAlchemy connection string env variable that Composer makes when SQLAlchemy is installed.

```
echo $AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN
```

Should return a connection string of the form: `mysql+mysqlconnector://<user>:<password>@<host>[:<port>]/<dbname>`.

Parsing the host, user and dbname from this i'm able to connect with:

```
mysql -h <host> -u <user> <dbname>
```